# C++はどの言語へ発展したのですか

Tags: c++

CはC++と発展したそうですが、C++はどの言語へ発展したのですか

Comment: C++の上位互換（ぽい）言語って見当たらないように思います。強いて言うならC++自身が発展中(C++14が最新？次はC++17らしい)。

Comment: C++ の後継を目指している言語としては、D とか Rust とかいろいろありますけど、ここで言う後継は、「C++ が使える場面で代用できる」 という意味で、文法的な互換性をある程度保ったもの、というものは (少なくとも有名どころでは) ないと思います。(え？ Objective-C++？ でもあれはほぼ Apple と GNUStep 専用の上、「代用できる」意味でさらなる後継 swift が出てたり……)

Answer (score 7):

O'REILLY のサイトによい図があるのでこちらを参考にされると良いでしょう。

[The History of Programming Languages - O'Reilly Media](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly//news/languageposter_0504.html)

[image: History of Programming Languages]

C++に限った話ではありませんが、大抵の言語は他の言語に大なり小なり影響を与えていますので一概にどれが後継であるとは言い難いというのが実情です。

他にも探したいなら検索キーワードは「programming language evolution tree」でどうぞ。

Comment: これ書籍の出版の話じゃないですか？

Answer (score 2):

CがC++に発展したのではなくて、CからC++が派生したと考えた方が良いと思います。

C++からJava, C#などが派生しているようですが、
現在、プログラミング言語はそれぞれが互いに影響しあって成長中のようです。

Answer (score 1):

補足で初めC＋＋は C with Classesと言った名前でCの拡張として生まれました。